Replace lever for hydraulic brakes
I was moving my mountain bike in a moving van, and the the brake lever was damaged in transit.
The brake is a tektro hydraulic, and it is the Front brake.
The connector to fluid tube is gone but no sign that any fluid has leaked.  Would installation of only a new brake lever  be a fix?  All riding is very casual, don't want expense of a mechanic.

Welcome to the site - Could you please add a photo of the damaged lever with [edit] ?

It's been a month now; how did you get on with your lever?

Depending on damage, you may be able to shorten the hose and add a new olive and barb, then reattach to the brake lever.
If the lever's boss is cracked/damaged you will need a new lever.  Attempting to glue/epoxy any crack is risky and may work at first, but eventually will fail due to internal pressures.
A replacement lever is the solution here.
Also, you've introduced air into the system - this will 100% need a bleed after refitting.  You'll need a brake bleed kit, some compatible fluid for your brake, basic hand tools, and patience.

For those who like me do not understand 'olive and barb', those are the names of the connector parts you might need to replace.
